# How is my dhcp server(192.168.1.1-100) conflicting with dorms dhcp which assign ip in range (172.20.64.1-254)?

Tags: networking, router

In my dorm, They have provided me ethernet port, I bought router and using it, I have connected lan cable to wan port and their network is in 172.20.64.1-254 and I am using dynamic Ip and 1 has beed assigned to my router and I have configured my own dhcp server over private ip 192.168.0.1-254, they came to me said that Its conflicting with their dhcp server and others are not able to use Internet, How is that possible??, they than said me to use my router as switch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DHCP works via broadcasts. That is a machine needing a IP address sends out a broadcast to 255.255.255.255 asking for the DHCP server to respond (expecting there only to be one DHCP server on a network segment).

In the above case - when ever a client on the network did a broadcast, your router would of offered a DHCP address in your own IP range, along with their DHCP server offering one in their range. However, anyone who used the IP your router offered them would not be able to route off the network.

You're lucky they only told you to use it as a switch - in most companies this would be highly frowned upon, and most universities too.

---

As for setting up your router - either do as they've said (operating it as a switch), or if you really wanted to be strange you could connect the wall port, to the WAN port of your router and have your router pick up a IP via DHCP, and then you could setup nat/firewall rules/etc on your router to effect your own devices.

Comment: What types of Nat rules I can define??? If u can give link or reference.. It will help me alot BTW Thanks for quick reply

Comment: Any that your router allows you to define...

Comment: If I limit my own routers IP range?? will others will use dorms dhcp server??

Comment: No, your router would hand out addresses until it ran out. At which point it'd likely start reusing addresses. You need to block the DHCP from being visible outside your router.